# Text widgets inline in scrollable frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to align text widgets horizontally and be able to scroll left and right the frame where are placed these widgets. The code below is almost what I want except the fact that my scrollbar doesn't work.

I found some example where it is said not to use pack or grid in Canvas. However, if I use place layout, my widgets simply disapear.

```
from tkinter import *


class MainView(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.sensorsStatsFrame = Frame(self.canvas)
        myscrollbar = Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=self.canvas.xview)
        myscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        test0 = Text(self.sensorsStatsFrame, bg="red", state=DISABLED, width=150)
        test1 = Text(self.sensorsStatsFrame, bg="green")
        test0.pack(side=LEFT)
        test1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.sensorsStatsFrame,anchor='nw')
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    root.wm_geometry("1100x500")
    root.wm_title("MongoDB Timed Sample Generator")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try putting a call to `self.update_idletasks()` between the `create_window()` and the setting of the `scrollregion`.  I suspect the problem is that at the time you call `bbox()`, the `sensorsStatsFrame` has not yet had a chance to adjust its size to accommodate the two `Text`s you've added to it, so your canvas's scroll region ends up as 1x1 pixel or something like that.

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to align text widgets horizontally and be able to scroll left and right the frame where are placed these widgets.

If i didn't misunderstand you, you should add an event function to your codes.

```
from tkinter import *


class MainView(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.sensorsStatsFrame = Frame(self.canvas)
        myscrollbar = Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=self.canvas.xview)
        myscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        test0 = Text(self.sensorsStatsFrame, bg="red", state=DISABLED, width=150)
        test1 = Text(self.sensorsStatsFrame, bg="green")
        test0.pack(side=LEFT)
        test1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.sensorsStatsFrame,anchor='nw')
# Call the function like the below.
        self.sensorsStatsFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
# Add below function to your codes.
    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    root.wm_geometry("1100x500")
    root.wm_title("MongoDB Timed Sample Generator")
    root.mainloop()
```